# Inner joins selecting multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

If I submit

```
Role.select("roles.character, actors.lname AS actors_lname").joins(:actor)
```

It returns:

```
Role Load (0.0ms) SELECT roles.character, actors.lname AS actors_lname 
FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "actors" ON "actors"."id" = "roles"."actor_id"
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Role id: nil, character: "Ellis Boyd 'Red' Redding">, 
#<Role id: nil, character: "Andy Dufresne">, #<Role id: nil, character: "Warden Norton">]>
```

Why doesn't the actors.lname column get displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select).

```
Order.select("orders.id, customers.name").joins(:customers)
```

You can fetch the associated values if you alias them

```
orders = Order.select("orders.id, customers.name AS customer_name").joins(:customers)

# you must call the method implicitly, or use .attributes
orders.first.customer_name
```

Please note that the value of `customer_name` will not show up in the inspection of the record. Therefore the following code

```
orders.first
```

in IRB will not print out the attribute.

Comment: @SimoneCarlettie, Thanks, but it seems to only show orders.id. For some reason customers.name doesn't show. If I do the reverse, it only shows custers.name and not orders.id. Any advice?

Comment: Use `AS`: `select("orders.id, customers.name AS customer_name")` and you will be able to call `customer_name` on `Order`.

Comment: @SimoneCarlettie, I've edited the post with the result of your advice. Any ideas how I can help you help me? :)

Comment: @SimoneCarlettie, I appreciate your help. However, I'm still confused. It sounds like you are saying that the second column cannot be displayed. But what would be the purpose to include two columns if you can't see both of them? Is there some way to get the output of the second column from the joined table?

Comment: The second column can be accessed calling the method with the same name of the `AS` in the result object. Check my example.